# Is "no" omitted in a series of coordinations?

Tags: coordination

> Because of Oklahoma!’s enormous subsequent influence, its novelties—**no** opening ensemble number, chorus girls in long dresses, dancers who don’t appear until late in the first act, the integrated score—have lost some of their original lustre.

Is "no" is omitted for the following juxtapositions? So in fact the sentence could be written as " **no** opening ensemble number, (**no**) chorus girls in long dresses, (**no**) dancers who don’t appear until late in the first act, (**no**) the integrated score"?

Comment: I don't think negating ***no*** is being implicitly extended in your examples. I haven't checked, but I bet Oklahoma's "novelties" ***did*** include "chorus girls in long dresses". And if ***no*** doesn't apply to that characteristic, it can't possibly apply to any subsequent elements. But this can only be established by ***semantics / context***. So far as the actual ***syntax*** of the cited construction is concerned, it's ***ambiguous*** right up until the final element (it's ungrammatical to assume ***no** the integrated score* with those two "determiners" ***no*** AND ***the***).

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oklahoma!), "Producer Mike Todd walked out after the first act during the tryout and wisecracked, 'No legs, no jokes, no chance.'" This certainly seems to confirm the long dresses. And certainly the integrated score was a feature. But I agree with FumbleFingers, it is formally ambiguous, and only semantics can resolve it.

Comment: Yes. It's the opening ensemble number that's lacking. "Oh What A Beautiful  Morning" is a *solo* (for Curly McLain). It *has* all the other things.

Comment: The answer can be guessed at, by closely considering items #2 and #3.  Chorus girls in *long* dresses would be unusual.  Likewise for dancers who...  *don't appear*. Therefore, these are *novelties*, and "no" isn't implied.